# Trying to find a fantasy novel duology about a halfing(?) archer who travels around his world to attempt to stop a war

Tags: story-identification

I don't remember much about the series, just that there are two books, the main character is some form of halfling if I remember correctly. He's an archer, and quite good at it. They travel all over a continent, and there's a final battle in a huge area called Hell's Basin or something similar. I read it a few years ago and suddenly got the urge to read it again.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe Dennis McKiernan's "Hel's Crucible" duology, "Into the Forge" and "Into the Fire"? [From Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0451457005)

> Finally, the story of the Great War of the Ban is told! Two young
>   wanderers are given a small copper coin by a dying human, who tells
>   them to deliver it "East to Agron" and "warn all," but dies before
>   explaining who they are to deliver it to, and what they are to warn
>   them of. Making matters worse, in order to deliver the message, the
>   pair must pass through a war in the East between the Black Mage Modru
>   and the alliance of free folk opposing him, and end up being drawn
>   into events which threaten to overwhelm them, save for the coin which
>   has much more significance than anyone could imagine!

[image]

> Tipperton and Beau, having delivered a mysterious coin to the
>   reclusive King Agron, discover that the coin was actually a plea for
>   help from King Blaine for aid in the Great War of the Ban. But despite
>   their deeds so far, the two adventurers are still not free from duty.
>   Tip burns to avenge the death of his lady-love, fallen in battle, and
>   Beau the healer cannot ignore the suffering of those around him. So
>   they join the fight, leading Agron's army into the lands of their
>   enemy, the Black Mage Modru, carrying with them an ancient prophecy of
>   victory....

[image]

He also wrote the "Iron Tower" trilogy and the sequel "Silver Call" duology. These books have been repackaged several times, including all in one omnibuses so the actual number of books can be a little vague. His "hobbits" are called warrows. Interestingly enough, the STRONG Lord of the Rings ties in his books came from "The Silver Call" which is basically a pastiche describing dwarves (with some Samwise Gamgee descendants) retaking Moria. So that initial homage roots his stuff into LOTR, which he then tries to get away from as much as possible in all the rest of it. Warrows are infamous for their archery, you can see one with a bow in the first book cover.

Comment: Yes, this has to be it. Book 2 ends with an apocalyptic battle in *Hel's Crucible* (which ends up breached and filled by the sea). The main protagonist Tipperton Thistledown is of a race called the Warrow, and he is an expert archer.

Comment: Yes, The Hel's Crucible series, that's the one. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of Binabik in the Memory, Sorrow, & Thorn series. It has been a while since I read the series, but he fits the description.

http://memorysorrowthorn.wikia.com/wiki/Binabik

Comment: Hmm. The picture shows him with a bow, but the description says he uses blow darts. In any case, does *Memory, Sorrow, and Thorn* have a location with a name similar to Hell’s Basin?